# What's wrong with this Oauth process for LinkedIn + email?

Tags: authentication, oauth, linkedin-api, laravel

I'm using the oneAuth bundle in laravel, based on NinjAuth from Fuel by Phil Sturgeon, I believe, and trying to get the user's email address.

I've added the proper scope to my request, and the LinkedIn auth screen successfully asks for the users permission for basic profile AND email address.. so far, so good..

A possible issue is: what is the proper name of the email field?
I've found references to `email-address`, `emailAddress`, 'emailaddress`...

The [docs indicate `email-address`](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#email), but its not working for me :)

I'm using the URL: [https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,member-url-resources,picture-url,location,public-profile-url,email-address)?format=json](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/%7E:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,member-url-resources,picture-url,location,public-profile-url,email-address)?format=json)

This is the problematic snippet from /bundles/oneauth/libraries/oauth/provider/linkedin.php

```
// Create a response from the request
return array(
    'uid'         => array_get($user, 'id'),
    // 'email'       => array_get($user, 'email-address)',
            // 'email'       => array_get($user, 'emailAddress)',
    'name'        => array_get($user, 'firstName').' '.array_get($user, 'lastName'),
    'image'       => array_get($user, 'pictureUrl'),
    'nickname'    => $nickname,
    'description' => array_get($user, 'headline'),
    'location'    => array_get($user, 'location.name'),
    'urls'        => array(
        'linkedin' => $linked_url,
    ),
);
```

If I uncomment the email field, the request fails somehow (URL still shows mysite.com/connect/callback but the favicon shows linkedin and i get ablank page in chrome: "`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.`")

If the email line in the code above IS commented out, I successfully receive all the other details and a new record is added to my users table and the table oneauth_clients, but email is naturally blank..

I must be missing something simple!

---

### Update

The request URL works with email-address, but returns a json object containing emailAddress!!

The script still dies if the return array code above includes `emailAddress`...

---

Here is [someone's success story](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/18171#comment-18171):

> "I made these two changes to the library and the demo.php respectively:
>
> `const _URL_REQUEST = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress';`
>
> `$response = $OBJ_linkedin->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,email-address)');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that the Request Token Call is:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,member-url-resources,picture-url,location,public-profile-url,email-address)?format=json`

but the json response is:

```
array(8) {
  ["emailAddress"]=>
  string(18) "email@email.com"
  ["firstName"]=>
  string(3) "Tim"
  ...
```

Note that in the first case email is named **email-address**, in the second **emailAddress**.

The secondary problem was a shortcoming of my code - now working perfectly!