# LinkedIn OAUTH - Still can't get email-address using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

Having read that since late last year LinkedIn finally have finally allowed us to retrieve the email address for the currently logged on user I've been failing to do so. I've read all the posts I can find on SO and elsewhere and as far as I can tell my code should be working. It returns just fine with all the other fields,

#### however, the email address field is always empty.

Here's my LinkedInClient class;

```
public class LinkedInClient2 : OAuthClient
{
    public static readonly ServiceProviderDescription LinkedInServiceDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription
    {
        AccessTokenEndpoint =
            new MessageReceivingEndpoint(
                "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken",
                HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
        RequestTokenEndpoint =
            new MessageReceivingEndpoint(
                "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress",
                HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
        UserAuthorizationEndpoint =
            new MessageReceivingEndpoint(
                "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate",
                HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
        TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
        ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V10a
    };

    public LinkedInClient2(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, IConsumerTokenManager tokenManager)
        : base("linkedIn", LinkedInServiceDescription, tokenManager)
    {
    }

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1031:DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes", Justification = "We don't care if the request fails.")]
    protected override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthenticationCore(AuthorizedTokenResponse response)
    {
        // See here for Field Selectors API http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1014
        const string ProfileRequestUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,headline,industry,summary,picture-url)";
        string accessToken = response.AccessToken;
        var profileEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(ProfileRequestUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
        HttpWebRequest request = this.WebWorker.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(profileEndpoint, accessToken);

        try
        {
            using (WebResponse profileResponse = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = profileResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    XDocument document = LoadXDocumentFromStream(responseStream);
                    string userId = document.Root.Element("id").Value;

                    // User Profile Fields - https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields
                    string firstName = document.Root.Element("first-name").Value;
                    string lastName = document.Root.Element("last-name").Value;
                    string userName = document.Root.Element("email-address").Value; // <<<<<< ERROR - always empty

                    var extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    extraData.Add("accesstoken", accessToken);
                    extraData.Add("name", userName);
                    extraData.AddDataIfNotEmpty(document, "picture-url");
                    extraData.AddDataIfNotEmpty(document, "location");
                    extraData.AddDataIfNotEmpty(document, "headline");
                    extraData.AddDataIfNotEmpty(document, "summary");
                    extraData.AddDataIfNotEmpty(document, "industry");

                    return new AuthenticationResult(
                        isSuccessful: true, provider: this.ProviderName, providerUserId: userId, userName: userName, extraData: extraData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return new AuthenticationResult(exception);
        }
    }

    internal static XDocument LoadXDocumentFromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        const int MaxChars = 0x10000; // 64k

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
        {
            MaxCharactersInDocument = MaxChars
        };
        return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(stream, settings));
    }
}
```

}

I realise that I'm supposed to add the `scope=r_emailaddress` to the `RequestTokenEndpoint` (which I have) but from the fiddler traces I can't even see that endpoint being fetched. Basically, it only every uses the `AccessTokenEndpoint` which presumably is something to do with my problem.

This is approximately how my ASP.Net MVC4.5 controller looks;

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public virtual ActionResult LinkedIn(string returnUrl)
    {
        var tokenMgr = new RepoOAuthTokenManager(_iOtk, LinkedInAppKey, LinkedInAppSecret);
        var iacp = new LinkedInClient2(LinkedInAppKey, LinkedInAppSecret, tokenMgr); // if none specified, LinkedInClient uses the AuthenticationOnlyCookieOAuthTokenManager which doesn't work for APIs
        var ioadp = new MyOauthDataProvider();
        var oasm = new OpenAuthSecurityManager(this.HttpContext, iacp, ioadp);

        var redirectUri = Url.ActionFullyQualified(this.nameof(c => c.LinkedIn(null)), null, new RouteValueDictionary(new { returnUrl = returnUrl }));
        AuthenticationResult ar = oasm.VerifyAuthentication(redirectUri);
        if (ar.Error == null)
        {
            if (ar.IsSuccessful)
                DoSomethingResultingInRedirect(redirectUri); // OK
            else
                oasm.RequestAuthentication(redirectUri);
        }
        else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ar.Error.Message);

        return View(this.nameof(c=>c.Login(null)));
    }//LinkedIn
```

I can't say I completely understand the extensibility mechanism in DotNetOpenAuth and I may be misunderstanding something so I'd appreciate some pointers.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions to this, although I still don't understand how to get my existing code to work as I'd expect, but hopefully this may help someone else;

(1) I went to [Making it easier for you to add default member permissions](http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/making-it-easier-you-add-default-member-permissions) and clicked on the [API admin](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer) page.

[image: OAuth Default Member Scopes]

Here you can select what scopes you want requested by default. It didn't work until I clicked a box (now disappeared) that was worded along the lines of `"[x] Make this permanent".` Once I'd done that I started to get the `email-address` field populated as I was expecting.

(2) I tried using the OAuth2 URL instead from information [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) and it seemed to work. I have also found an implementation of an OAuth2 client [here](https://github.com/sanction10/DotNetOpenAuth.LinkedInOAuth2/blob/master/DotNetOpenAuth.LinkedInOAuth2/LinkedInOAuth2Client.cs) which looks like a good start. I suspect that in the long run, an OAuth2 upgrade (once the spec is more static) will yield better overall mileage.

For now though, I'm out of the pit of despair, but other answers are still welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833850/whats-wrong-with-this-oauth-process-for-linkedin-email/14835710#14835710).. maybe this is relevant for you:

My Request Token Call is:

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,member-url-resources,picture-url,location,public-profile-url,email-address)?format=json

but the json response is:

```
array(8) {
  ["emailAddress"]=>
  string(18) "email@email.com"
  ["firstName"]=>
  string(3) "Tim"
  ...
```

Note that in the first case email is named **email-address**, in the second **emailAddress**.

Comment: Actually, I since I found out that LinkedIn have deprecated the OAUTH1 flow and they have an OAUTH2 flow. Since migrating to that I've been better off all round. It's a far simpler model to implement as well.